# Is it possible to "override" the Earth magnetic field locally?

Tags: magnetic-fields, estimation, gyroscopes, sensor, geomagnetism

For a mobile application I am developing I would like to know which direction the phone is facing. In the outdoor we can of course use the magneto meter in combination with a gyroscope.

However, indoors the magnetometer is too jumpy to use.

This made me wonder whether it would be possible to place a electormagnet in a hall which would completely "override" the earth magnetic, so that magneto meter in the phone would yield steady values.

The hall would measure about 50 x 50 meter.

Comment: Why do you want to eliminate the Earth's magnetic field, when that's what you're using to determine the phone's orientation?

Comment: Well, I dont know all the sources which can cause magnetic interference beforehand, so I rather eliminate them all by installing a stronger magnet at a known position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you know the magnitude and direction of the Earth's field at that spot, it's very possible! Suppose you measure the magnitude of the field as $B_{earth}$ in tesla (T), and you set up a solenoid with $n$ turns per m. Then the current $I$ you need to run in the solenoid is as follows:

$$I = \frac{B_{earth}}{\mu_0 n}$$

where $\mu_0$ is the permeability of free space. Then the field generated by the solenoid will cancel the field from the Earth. Note that there will still be a non-zero field gradient, so the cancellation will only be perfect in one location, but the gradient of the Earth's field is typically small, so this shouldn't affect things much.

**However,**

The Earth's field doesn't vary too much over small regions of space. Therefore, a jumpy magnetometer would not be the result of Earth's field, but rather because either:

- Your magnetometer isn't sensitive enough or is somehow defective, or
- There are sources of magnetic interference indoors.

The first one is unlikely, since the problem only appears to happen indoors. The second is usually the case, since anything that has a current running through it generates a magnetic field. As long as the sources of interference are *static* (i.e. there's just a constant DC current running through the source), the solenoid setup should still work. But if the sources have AC current or time-varying DC current running through them, the solenoid won't be of much use. In that case, placing the magnetometer inside a Faraday cage (essentially a conducting cage connected to ground) will isolate it from any sources of interference.